# How can I fix my chart so that the scale of the x axis is defined by a group of labels?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

js, I am using v3. I'm pretty sure the problem with my chart is with my x-axis.

I have this structure:

```
[
 {date: "OCT 2020", close: 57370}
 {date: "SEP 2020", close: 60100}
 {date: "AGO 2020", close: 62530}
 {date: "JUL 2020", close: 68840}
 {date: "MAY 2020", close: 91470}
 {date: "ABR 2020", close: 54130}
 {date: "MAR 2020", close: 57960}
 {date: "FEB 2020", close: 55720}
 {date: "ENE 2020", close: 54360}
]
```

the `x` axis would be the key "date" and the `y-axis` would be `close`, I don't know how to define the `x-axis` so that each indicates that the values of the x axis will be a label. (no value will be repeated on my x-axis, and my data is sorted)

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style> /* set the CSS */
 
body { font: 12px Arial;}
 
path { 
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2;
  fill: none;
}
 
.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
 
</style>
<body>
 
<!-- load the d3.js library --> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
 
<script>
 
// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
 
 
// Set the ranges
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
 
// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(5);
 
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(5);

 // Define the line
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { console.log(x(d.date)); return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { console.log(y(d.close)); return y(d.close); }); 

// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
 
// Get the data
 let data=[
 {date: "OCT 2020", close: 57370},
 {date: "SEP 2020", close: 60100},
 {date: "AGO 2020", close: 62530},
 {date: "JUL 2020", close: 68840},
 {date: "MAY 2020", close: 91470},
 {date: "ABR 2020", close: 54130},
 {date: "MAR 2020", close: 57960},
 {date: "FEB 2020", close: 55720},
 {date: "ENE 2020", close: 54360}
]

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));


    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);

    // Add the valueline path.
    svg.append("path")  
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", valueline(data));
 
    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")     
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);
 
    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")     
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);
  


 
</script>
</body>
```

```css
body { font: 12px Arial;}
 
path { 
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2;
  fill: none;
}
 
.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
```

I relied on this example:
https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/4414436

how can I fix it?

Comment: can you provide working example in codesandbox or jsfiddle??

Comment: @Abhishek this is my live code: http://plnkr.co/edit/qR8QX8J7A6fLZsco?open=lib%2Fscript.js

Comment: I relied on this example:
https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/4414436

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code::
http://plnkr.co/edit/pdjNBWCYd91drndL?open=lib%2Fscript.js

This is using D3v3 you might want to upgrade your D3 version and go through D3docs because there are lots of changes in the latest D3 version.

Below is the basic working example with your data

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style> /* set the CSS */
 
body { font: 12px Arial;}
 
path { 
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2;
  fill: none;
}
 
.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
 
</style>
<body>
 
<!-- load the d3.js library --> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
 
<script>
 
// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
 
 
// Set the ranges
var x = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(["OCT 2020",
"SEP 2020",
"AGO 2020",
"JUL 2020",
"MAY 2020",
"ABR 2020",
"MAR 2020",
"FEB 2020",
"ENE 2020"])
.rangePoints([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
 
// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(100);
 
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(10);

 // Define the line
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) {  return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) {  return y(d.close); }); 

// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
 
// Get the data
 let data=[
 {date: "OCT 2020", close: 57370},
 {date: "SEP 2020", close: 60100},
 {date: "AGO 2020", close: 62530},
 {date: "JUL 2020", close: 68840},
 {date: "MAY 2020", close: 91470},
 {date: "ABR 2020", close: 54130},
 {date: "MAR 2020", close: 57960},
 {date: "FEB 2020", close: 55720},
 {date: "ENE 2020", close: 54360}
]

    // Scale the range of the data
    // x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);

    // Add the valueline path.
    svg.append("path")  
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", valueline(data));
 
    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")     
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);
 
    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")     
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Thank you very much, I hope I don't bother you, but do you know what I have to do to have a curve line chart?

Comment: @yavg you can add .interpolate("basis");  at d3.svg.line